# When i am executing it it says can't read s0 not such variable. Please

Tags: global-variables, tcl, tk-toolkit

```
proc ok { } {
exec echo "LIST OF TOKENS REQUESTED TO BE KILLED BY THE USER" >killed_file; #the information will be dumped in your a file named killed_file
    global s0 s1 s2 s3 s4 s5
    if {$s0} {exec echo "$s0 choice a" >>killed_file}
    if {$s1} {exec echo "$s1 choice b" >>killed_file}
    if {$s2} {exec echo "$s2 choice c" >>killed_file}
    if {$s3} {exec echo "$s3 choice d" >>killed_file}
    if {$s4} {exec echo "$s4 choice e" >>killed_file}
    if {$s5} {exec echo "$s5 choice f" >>killed_file}
destroy .top
}
```

executing it says can't read s0 no such variable and same for other variables.

Comment: The error is what it says, there are no such variables... What makes you think that these variables exist?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the variables s0 to s5 have not been set.

If you want to skip them when they do not exists you can use the command `info exists name` to test this.  Also you are using a very strange method to write to your file.  A more straightforward alternative (not tested) would be:

```
proc ok { } {
    #the information will be dumped in your a file named killed_file
    set kf [open killed_file w]
    puts $kf "LIST OF TOKENS REQUESTED TO BE KILLED BY THE USER"
    global s0 s1 s2 s3 s4 s5
    if {[info exists s0]} {puts $kf "$s0 choice a"}
    if {[info exists s1]} {puts $kf "$s1 choice b"}
    if {[info exists s2]} {puts $kf "$s2 choice c"}
    if {[info exists s3]} {puts $kf "$s3 choice d"}
    if {[info exists s4]} {puts $kf "$s4 choice e"}
    if {[info exists s5]} {puts $kf "$s5 choice f"}
    close $kf
    destroy .top
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Can you please help me in how can i define them  ?

Comment: You will just be doing `set s0 something` etc.  The exact something depends on the logic of your application, which I do not know.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should pass these in as arguments, shouldn't use 'exec' to write to a file, etc...

Below is my approach, which is bad and I'd not code in a real project, but much better than 'globals' and system calls to write to files:

```tcl
proc ok {s0 s1 s2 s3 s4 s5} {
   set FH [open killed_file 'w']

   puts $FH "LIST OF TOKENS REQUESTED TO BE KILLED BY THE USER"
   if {$s0} {puts $FH "$s0 choice a"}
   if {$s1} {puts $FH "$s1 choice b"}
   if {$s2} {puts $FH "$s2 choice c"}
   if {$s3} {puts $FH "$s3 choice d"}
   if {$s4} {puts $FH "$s4 choice e"}
   if {$s5} {puts $FH "$s5 choice f"}
   close $FH
   destroy .top
}
```

If you give more details on what you are trying to achieve, we may be able to give a bit more help.